# How to break a while loop reading from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the loop to break if any of  the words from the input are not found in the text file, so far I have:

```
import re
TypeFood = input("What food would you like to order?")
words = TypeFood.split()
with open("HungryHorseMenu.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(word.lower() in re.findall('\w+', line.lower()) for word in words):
            splitted_line = line.split(',')
            print(splitted_line[0])
        else:
            print("We do not serve what you would like to eat.")
            break
```

My text file is :

```
Vegetarian pizza, 
Margarita pizza,   
Meat feast pizza, 
Spaghetti bolognese, pasta, italian
Spaghetti carbonara, pasta, italian
Tagliatteli, pasta, italian


Cheeseburger, american
Chicken burger, american
Veggie burger, american
Hot dog, american


Chicken curry, indian
Lamb curry, indian
Vegetable curry, indian
```

When i type something that is not in the text file it does break but if i type something that is in the text file it prints out the menu but also at the end prints we do not serve what you would like.
e.g.

```
I would like pizza
```

Output:

```
Vegetarian pizza 
Margarita pizza   
Meat feast pizza
We do not serve what you would like to eat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through each line, and when it reaches the first line that doesn't contain your phrase, then it gives an error even if it found something. You want something like this:

```
import re
TypeFood = input("What food would you like to order?")
words = TypeFood.split()
with open("HungryHorseMenu.txt", "r") as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        if any(word.lower() in re.findall('\w+', line.lower()) for word in words):
            splitted_line = line.split(',')
            found = True
            print(splitted_line[0])
    if found==False:
        print("We do not serve what you would like to eat.")
```

Comment: This works thanks, but could you please add me some comments to explain what the lines you added do, because im a beginner and i don't understand what they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all valid items into a list. If the list is empty which means there's no valid item, if not empty, print all valid items.

```
import re
TypeFood = input("What food would you like to order?")
words = TypeFood.split()
with open("sample.csv", "r") as f:
    valid_items = list()
    for line in f:
        if any(word.lower() in re.findall('\w+', line.lower()) for word in words):
            splitted_line = line.split(',')
            valid_items.append(splitted_line[0])


    if not valid_items:
        print("We do not serve what you would like to eat")
    else:
        for item in valid_items:
            print(item)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
python test.py                                           
What food would you like to order?pizza
Vegetarian pizza
Margarita pizza
Meat feast pizza

python test.py                                 
What food would you like to order?indian
Chicken curry
Lamb curry
Vegetable curry

python test.py                                  
What food would you like to order?canadian
We do not serve what you would like to eat
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to invert the validation:

```
for line in f:
    if !any(word.lower() in re.findall('\w+', line.lower()) for word in words):
        print("We do not serve what you would like to eat.")
        break
    else:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')
        print(splitted_line[0])
```

Comment: use `not` other than `!`   The logic is broken. try input `pizza`, it gives your `We do not...` which is not correct.